# android progressdialog not appearing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm posting this question because I can't really figure out what is causing, sometimes, a ProgressDialog not appearing. I've looked for all similar questions but none was helpfull form me
I have this method in a helper class

```
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static void ShowProgressDialog(Context context, String title, String message, boolean cancellable) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog == null)
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, message);
        else
            LogHelper.WriteLogInfo("ALERT_DIALOG", "progress dialog already exists");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogHelper.WriteLogError("error showing progress dialog", e);
    }
}
```

and I call it from my activity in this way

```
DialogHelper.ShowProgressDialog(this, "title","progress bar  text",false);
new MyAsyncTask().execute("inputString");
```

everything works very well, but sometimes the ProgressDialog do not appears, and there are not error logs that should have been written by the LogHelper.WriteLogError in the catch block.

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this behavior?

Comment: have you tried executing `DialogHelper.ShowProgressDialog(this, "progress bar  text");` from AsyncTask ?

Comment: This code won't compile, for example you're not passing the right params to ShowProgressDialog(). Please edit the question to show how you actually use the code.

Comment: The AsyncTask is a standalone class used all around the project to implement web services calls, and every single web service operation has a different waiting message, so I show the ProgressDialog before each call in order to show the proper message

Comment: but in your showprogress dialog method you have pass 3 parameters so i have changed it with ...so check it.

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal I have fixed the code, actually I have 3 different signatures for ShowProgressDialog, but the real implementation is in the code I've posted

Comment: Common pitfall is blocking the UI thread with something, usually `AsyncTask.get()`.

Comment: @laalto I'm not using AsyncTask.get()

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

```
DialogHelper.ShowProgressDialog(this, "progress bar  text");
new MyAsyncTask.execute("inputString")
```

with

```
DialogHelper.ShowProgressDialog(getapplicationcontext(), "progress bar Title" , "Message",false);
new MyAsyncTask.execute("inputString")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progress= new ProgressDialog(this);

progress.setTitle("Your Text");

progress.show();

MyTask tak=new MyTask();

task.execute();
```

Comment: can you explain the difference please?

Comment: if we want to load the data at the time of activity creation then show the dialog and then execute your task. and in the onPost method dismiss the dialog. it always work..

Comment: I'm not showing the ProgressDialog at the time of activity creation, but in a onClickListener, when the Activity has been completely created. I know it should always work, but I've seen with my eyes the ProgressDialog not being shown

Comment: ok do same work in the onClickListner..
like
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   ProgressDialog progress= new ProgressDialog(this);

progress.setTitle("Your Text");

progress.show();
   }
  });

Comment: If you have a look at android source code, you will see that in the implementation of ProgressDialog.show() method, there is the exact same code you are suggesting, the ProgressDialog constructor is invoked and all setter methods are invoked on the instance, so I don't think there is difference betweeen my code and yours

Answer (score 0):

Note that AsyncTask has a method

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Show ProgressDialog if desired
    if (doUseProgressDialog)
    {
        // Note that all these parameters are passed to the containing class in the constructor
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressDialog.setMessage(progressDialogMessage);
        progressDialog.setTitle(progressDialogTitle);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialogStyle);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

which allows for UI-modifications (e.g. showing a progressDialog). Furthermore you can apply updates to the UI in

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress)
```

I suggest you subclass AsyncTask for your needs and pass the required title, message etc. in the constructor.

Comment: I know that AsyncTask runs the onPreExecute method in the UI thread, but using my code inside an Activity isn't the UI thread as well?

Comment: That's true. But I experienced that Dialogs tend to behave unanticipated, especially if constructed one line before another task (such as AsyncTask). However using onPreExecute() worked out well for me. You should give it a try.

Comment: Ok it should be an option, the only problem is that I should change every single call to this AsyncTask, I'm speaking about 50/60 calls. If no one will provide a better solution, I will give it a try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Way

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setMessage("Message");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
Thread mThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       /*Your Code*/
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
mThread.start();
```